How to Embed a LWC component within another LWC
I have a couple questions related to an implementation:

Does Salesforce support embedding a LWC within another LWC on a SFDC page?
Would these two LWC conflict with each other or could they work together?
Could we build an LWC and use an alternate database outside of the Salesforce stack to populate the date of that component (such as an external SQL server)?


https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-for-aura-developers/compose-components but your question sounds like a XY Problem. Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to accomplish.


Yes, you can use a  element to allow you to drag and drop another lwc into the parent lwc.
Really depends what the two lwcs are trying to do.
I'm sure this can be achieved by external object or an API call to your external service. Probably best with an apex class which you call from the lwc


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
